# Compare multiple element in a list

Tags: c#, list, extract

I would like to extract from a list a data of an element who respect different criteria like below :

My list contains :

```
1, name1, Time, quantity
2, name2, Time, quantity
3, name1, Time+1, quantity+1
4, name2, Time+1, quantity+1
....
```

My goal :

```
if (MyList.Contains(name1 && name2))
{
    if (name1(quantity) == name2(quantity) && name1(Time) == name2(Time))
    {
        return quantity;
    }
}
```

How i create my List :

```
public class OCO1 : IEquatable<OCO1>
{
        public DateTime OrderCreatedTime {get; set;}
        public int ID {get; set;}
        public decimal Quantity {get; set;}
        public string Tag {get; set;}

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "ID: " + ID + "   Name: " + Tag;
        }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) return false;
            OCO1 objAsOCO1 = obj as OCO1;
            if (objAsOCO1 == null) return false;
            else return Equals(objAsOCO1);
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return ID;
        }
        public bool Equals(OCO1 other)
        {
            if (other == null) return false;
            return (this.ID.Equals(other.ID));
        }
    // Should also override == and != operators.
}

public partial class Base
{
List<OCO1> CreatedTimeOrder = new List<OCO1>();

if (order.Tag.Equals("name1"))
{
CreatedTimeOrder.Add( new OCO1() {OrderCreatedTime = order.CreatedTime, ID = order.Id, Quantity = order.Quantity, Tag = "name1"});
}

if (order.Tag.Equals("name2"))
{
CreatedTimeOrder.Add( new OCO1() {OrderCreatedTime = order.CreatedTime, ID = order.Id, Quantity = order.Quantity, Tag = "name2"});
}
```

I don't see how to do that. Any help appreciate !

"more details for edit the post jskfjhsfsjfsgfghsfshsfghjsfgsdsjffsgfgsgfyjhdfusygfyusgfuygfgsdvfvsdufvusvfuvsufvyusdfgyugfdyugfusgfuysfgusfgusgfuysgfgsugfusgfugfgsfgufgusfugydsfg"

Comment: Not that it really matters, since both types are enumerable, but is that really a List? Looks like it would be a DataTable.

Comment: Yes it doesn't seem a list but it is :)

Comment: In your example there are multiple entries fulfilling your criteria. You want to have the first one or all of them? 1, 2 as well as 3,4 do have the names: name1, name2 and have the same time and quantity.

Comment: Is there any way you can convert the type to a DataTable? If you do, it is easy to achieve your required output with a DataTable.

Comment: I want to get the quantity if the Time is the same for name1 and name2. I don't see how to explain it otherwise..

Comment: Post your code to show how you are storing the data in list?

Comment: @guerinremi this is true for the combination of 1 and 2 and for the combination 3 and 4 in your given example. Should the function return in this case `quantity` or `quantity+1`?

Comment: I edited my post for more details.

Comment: Instead of adding garbage text at the end, it would be nice to see what the expected output should be, because the pseudo "goal-code" is not exactly clear to me.

Comment: Do you just want a list of quantities in the end (i.e. `{ quantity, quantity+1 }`) since both those quantities belong to groups that contain the same time and the desired names.

Comment: I edited My goal, hope this is more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question, you want to find all the records that have the same `Quantity` and `Time` values, and which contain both `"name1"` and `"name2"`, and for each of these you want to select the `Quantity` property.

If that's correct, we can use a little `System.Linq` to group the items by their `OrderCreatedTime` and `Quantity` properties, filter to only the groups that have at least one item with each desired name, and then select the `Quantity` property from the group:

```
List<decimal> relevantQuantities = CreatedTimeOrder
    .GroupBy(item => new {item.OrderCreatedTime, item.Quantity})
    .Where(group => group.Any(item => item.Tag == "name1") &&
                    group.Any(item => item.Tag == "name2"))
    .Select(g => g.Key.Quantity)
    .ToList();
```

If that's *not* correct, please clarify exactly what you expect to be returned.

Comment: It seems to be exactly that, i didn't think that groupby be able to do that. i implement it in my code tommorow and tell you the result. Thank you very much !

Comment: Hello Rufus, although "relevantQuantities" is in decimal, the return value is int.. I have to get it in decimal.

Comment: I have change .Tolist(); at the end of the linq query by .FirstOrDefault(); the return is in decimal. I edit your post if i can.

Comment: `relevantQuantities` is a `List<decimal>`, since it's returning all the quantities that match the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the author's comment:

> I want to get the quantity if the Time is the same for name1 and name2. I don't see how to explain it otherwise.

Imagine this class, abbreviated for the simplicity of this answer.

```cs
public class Data
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Time { get; set; }
}
```

And this collection

```cs
List<Data> list = new List<Data>() { 
  new Data() { Name = "Name1", Time = 1 },
  new Data() { Name = "Name2", Time = 2 },
  new Data() { Name = "Name3", Time = 3 },
  new Data() { Name = "Name4", Time = 4 },
 };
```

You can do it with LINQ

```cs
string searchArray = new string[] { "Name1", "Name2" };
// Filtering only elements with Name equals name1 or name2
var filtered = list.Where(d => searchArray.Contains(d.Name)); 
if(filtered.GroupBy(d => d.Time).Count() == 1) // If there is only one group of Time
 return filtered.Sum(d => d.Time); // it will return 3 (1 + 2)
else
  // do another thing
```

Comment: You should move `new string[] { "Name1", "Name2" }` out of the `Where` clause.

Comment: FYI, no need to call `ToArray()` on the group since `GroupBy` returns an `IEnumerable`

Comment: Sorry I was in a hurry, missed these improvements. Answer edited.